# LESS extend root selector

Tags: css, less

I need generate css like this:

```
header.is-sticky .menu nav > ul > li > a span {
    color: #555555;
}
```

My LESS code looks like tihs:

```
header {
  .menu {
    nav {
      > ul > li {
        > a {
          span {
            .is-sticky & {
              color: #555555;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it is generated to this wrong unwanted result:

```
.is-sticky header .menu nav > ul > li > a span {
    color: #555555;
}
```

How to change LESS script to generate required result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your correct code

```css
.menu {
    nav {
      > ul > li {
        > a {
          span {
            header.is-sticky & {
              color: #555555;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

The output will be shown as you want

```
header.is-sticky .menu nav > ul > li > a span {
  color: #555555;
}
```

Comment: I can not use it because header as my root has many many changes inside, not only this.

Comment: There is not really any other way. You can always start another cascade. Or give meaningful class names to your elements and not use such long selectors.

Comment: @cloned is right there is no another way I think also.